# HDFS: Remove a directory with a colon (":") in its name

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to remove a HDFS directory which has a colon (`:`) in its name. I have tried a lot of ways but nothing worked.

The folder name is `"/data/TestFolder:Click1"`

I tried the following commands:

`hadoop fs -rm -r /data/TestFolder:Click1`

`hadoop fs -rm -r "/data/TestFolder:Click1"`

`hadoop fs -rm -r '/data/TestFolder:Click1'`

`hadoop fs -rm -r /data/TestFolder%3AClick1`

I tried searching on Apache issues [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-13) but I'm not able to find a solution. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: How did you create the file?  Did you try `hadoop fs -rm -r /data/TestFolder*Click1`?

Comment: The file was created through hbase export command. I tried hadoop fs -rm -r /data/TestFolder*Click1 command as well but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I did some digging looks like this issue has a long history.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14217 - Object Storage: support colon in object path, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7945 - Document that Path objects do not support ":" in them and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3257 - Path should handle all characters.